# USB failing silently on linux

Tags: linux, usb

I have an external USB hard drive which works perfectly most of the time but sometimes when I plug it in nothing happens.

Nothing is outputted to dmesg when this happens. Rebooting always fixes the problem.

How to I go about diagnosing this if there is nothing in dmesg?

Linux version 3.8.0-31-generic on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: It sounds like a cable problem.. how old is the usb hard drive? I've had similar issues, and the problem was the usb cable, one wire was cut and needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is not always enough power from USB to start hard drive. Try using additional power supply for the drive, or use [USB Y-Cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003WV5DMO) to provide up to 1A to the drive.